# Closed form solution to operator norm minimization?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-control, variational-analysis

Is it possible to give a closed form solution to the value or minimizer to the following problem?
$$
\inf \{ \|AX + B\|_{\rm op} : \|X\|_{F} = 1\}
$$
Above, $A, X, B$ are square matrices, and $\|\cdot\|_{\rm op}$ is the operator norm, also given by the largest singular value, for instance. $\|\cdot\|_F$ is Frobenius norm (sometimes also called Hilbert-Schmidt norm). We can assume that $A, B$ are invertible.

An easy case is when the dimension is 1:
$$
\inf\{|ax + b| : |x| = 1\}  = \min\{|a - b|, |a + b|\}. 
$$
Is there a way to generalize this for larger dimensions?

Comment: Note that your infimum could be more simply expressed as $||a| - |b||$.

Comment: In general, we can say that for all such $X$,
$$
\|AX + B\|_{\text{op}} \geq |\|AX\|_{\text{op}} - \|B\|_{\text{op}}|,
$$
$\|AX\|_{\text{op}} \leq \|A\|_{\text{op}}\|X\|_{\text{op}}$, and $\|X\|_{\text{op}} \leq \|X\|_F = 1$. Perhaps one of these results might be useful

Comment: It is also notable that the related problem
$$
\inf\{\|AX + B\|_F : \|X\|_F\}
$$
can be nicely reframed. If $x = \operatorname{vec}(X)$ and $b = \operatorname{vec}(B)$, then 
$$
\|AX + B\|_F^2 = \|(I \otimes A)x + b\|^2.
$$